# How to customise flex sdk classes?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, customization

I have modifyed XMLEncoder class from Flex SDK (XMLEncoder.as)

After it I run my project but I don't see any changes...

What should I do to realy modify project's behaviour?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not usually recommended but what you are trying to do is Monkey Patching.  You can just copy your modified source file into your project and then you application's XMLEncoder will overwrite the one used in Flex (because of how the Flex linker works).  This doesn't work with the framework RSLs though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see changes, this means sources aren't used - swc is used instead. To use modified sources, recreate folder structure for the class you modified and put source there. You may see a lot of errors (most of the time because `include` directive), this means you need to copy files needed to satisfy dependencies.

Maybe this is not the right way, but sometimes it's the only option to fix broken Flex class, so professional Flex developer masters it sooner or later :)